# Calculate in closed form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(1/n) H_n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Playing with Taylor series is not helpful enough. What else would you try out?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(1/n) H_n}{n}$$
$$\approx 2.1496160413898356727147400526167103602143301206321$$
It's easy to see the series converges since $\arctan(1/n) \approx 1/n$ when $n$ large.
Maybe its integral representation makes us feel more comfortable

$$1/4\int_0^1 \frac{ 2(\gamma  \pi  x \coth (\pi  x)+\gamma) +i x \left(\psi ^{(0)}(-i x)^2-\psi ^{(0)}(i x)^2-\psi ^{(1)}(-i x)+\psi ^{(1)}(i x)\right)}{ x^2} \, dx$$

Comment: Any reason you expect a closed form? Seems like a pretty random sum.

Comment: @Winther I calculated similar (the similar word is discussable) series in closed form. I was curious to receive some clever ideas, strategies, not downvotes, or reasons for that I should not expect a closed form if some consider this is the case here.

Comment: One should never expect a closed form if the summand is non-trivial imo, but then again some really crazy sums do have closed forms. Trying your numerical value on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) gives no matches. If anyone can solve your integral it's [Cleo](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/97378/cleo)...

Comment: Do either $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(1/n)}{n}$ or $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+1/n)H_n}{n}$ possess a closed form?

Answer (score 3):

We just need to compute:
$$ \mathcal{J}(m)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^{2m}} \tag{1} $$
but Euler's theorem (see [Flajolet and Salvy](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf), $(2.2)$) gives:
$$ \mathcal{J}(m)= (1+m)\,\zeta(2m+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{2m-2}\,\zeta(k+1)\zeta(2m-k)\tag{2}$$
as a consequence of:
$$ \text{Res}\left[\left(\psi(-s)+\gamma\right)^2,s=n\right]=2 H_n,\tag{3}$$
hence:
$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n}\,\arctan\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2m-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^{2m}}=\\=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2m-1}\left((1+m)\,\zeta(2m+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{2m-2}\,\zeta(k+1)\zeta(2m-k)\right)=\\=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2m-1}\cdot[x^{2m}]\,g(x)\tag{4}$$

where:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} g(x) &=& -\gamma-\frac{\gamma x}{2}- \psi(1-x)-\gamma x \psi(1-x)-\frac{x}{2} \psi(1-x)^2+\frac{x}{2} \psi'(1-x)\\&=&\frac{\pi^2}{4}\,x+2\zeta(3)\,x^2+\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4)\,x^3+(3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3))\,x^4+\ldots\tag{5}\end{eqnarray*} $$

So we have:
$$ S = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{g(ix)+g(-ix)}{2x^2}\,dx.\tag{6} $$

Comment: Good progress (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: there is still a lot of work to do. The RHS of $(4)$ is obviously left unchanged by replacing $g(x)$ by $\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}$, that probably has a nice closed form by the reflection formulas. Then, the RHS of $(4)$ can be seen as an integral over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, but it's a very nice start with some good ideas to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-nx}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\arctan \frac1n$$,
(which by the way is a famous exercise in "differentiating under the integral sign" for computing $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x }{x}dx$ ).
Now, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}x^n=-\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-t)}{t(1-t)}dt= \mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\log^2(1-x)$$
so another integral representation of the sum would be 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} \left(\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{-x})+\frac12\log^2(1-e^{-x})\right )dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{(\gamma+\psi_0(-z))^2}{z^2+x^2}$. On $z=Re^{i[0,2\pi]}$, $f(z)\sim\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln^2{R}}{R^2}\right)$, so the residue theorem gives
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),n\right)+\sum_{\pm}\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),\pm ix\right)+\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),0\right)=0\tag1
\end{align}
At the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),n\right)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\frac{1}{(z^2+x^2)(z-n)^2}+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\frac{2H_n}{(z^2+x^2)(z-n)}\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^2+x^2}-2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n}{(n^2+x^2)^2}\tag2
\end{align}
At $z=\pm ix$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{\pm}\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),\pm ix\right)
&=\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(-ix))^2}{2ix}-\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(ix))^2}{2ix}\\
&=\operatorname{Im}\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(-ix))^2}{x}\tag3
\end{align}
At $z=0$,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0)
&=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2(z^2+x^2)}=0\tag4
\end{align}
Substituting $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$ into $(1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^2+x^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n}{(n^2+x^2)^2}+\operatorname{Im}\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(ix))^2}{2x}\tag5
\end{align}
and integrating $(5)$ from $0$ to $1$ gives
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n\operatorname{arccot}{n}}{n}
&=\color{darkblue}{\operatorname{Im}\int^1_0\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(ix))^2}{2x}\ {\rm d}x}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n(n^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\operatorname{arccot}{n}}{n^2}\\
&=\color{darkblue}{\mathcal{I}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2(n-i)}-\frac{1}{2(n+i)}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n(n^2+x^2)}\ {\rm d}x\\
&=\color{darkblue}{\mathcal{I}}+\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Re}\psi_0(1+i)+\int^1_0\frac{\gamma+\operatorname{Re}\psi_0(1+ix)}{2x^2}{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Re}\psi_0(1+i)+\operatorname{Re}\int^1_0\frac{\gamma+\psi_0(1+ix)-ix(\gamma+\psi_0(ix))^2}{2x^2}\ {\rm d}x\\
&\tag6
\end{align}
The remaining integral is quite hard to approach as of now.